# Understanding how to use rust TOKIO library

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I want to learn the rust Tokio library.  To facilitate this I want to write an ASYNC TCP logger in rust.

Basically a TCP client that connects to a TCP server (172.16.10.10 port 7777) and just logs messages received asynchronously file to a log file.   I want the main function to read user input from the console - in my case was for pressing ‘q’ key - simulate the program doing some other task.

I expect to receive multiple TCP responses whilst waiting for user to press ‘q’ key.

I am trying to workout how to read and log multiple TCP responses independently of waiting for the user input

```
let mut buf_reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
let mut data = vec![];
buf_reader.read_to_end(&mut data).await.unwrap();
log_writer.write_all(&data).await.unwrap();`
```

Here is the code I have

```
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio::prelude::*;
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write, BufWriter, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let ip = "172.16.10.10:7777";
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect(ip).await.unwrap();
    let message = [0x16, 0x02];
    stream.write(&message).await.unwrap();

    // Open a file for logging
    let file = File::create("log.txt").unwrap();
    let mut log_writer = BufWriter::new(file);

    println!("Press 'q' to exit and receive response:");
    stdout().flush().unwrap();
    let mut input = String::new();
    stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
    if input.trim() == "q" {
        // SIMULATE doing time consuming task
        println!(“Quitting”);
    }
}
```

I tried the following but this loops over the waiting for user input.  This is not behaviour I want.  I want to be reading and logging the TCP messages independent of the awaiting user inout.

```
loop {
    stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
    if input.trim() == "q" {
        break;
    }
    let mut data = vec![];
    buf_reader.read_to_end(&mut data).await.unwrap();
    log_writer.write_all(&data).await.unwrap();
}
```

Comment: My bad. Updated https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html

Answer (score 1):

When I needed async multithreading, I defined multiple `async fn` to do what I want, then called them in `async fn main` as:

```
let handle1 = tokio::spawn(do_it("test_data.txt"));
let handle2 = tokio::spawn(do_something_else("test_data.txt"));
handle1.await.unwrap();
handle2.await.unwrap();
```

Since I'm zealous about keeping `fn main` as minimal as possible, this may not exactly work for you, but may give you a direction.